# ASP.NET MVC 5 Adding roles to an existing application w. Forms authentication (C#)

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication, roles

situation is as follows:
I have an existing MVC 5 application and created some very, very basic log-in functionality for it. I just have a table for users and passwords in my database, and use forms authentication to check if a user exists (and some actions can only be done if you are logged in).

Now I would like to extend the authentication system to use roles. From what I gather, I need to make a table in the database with roles, and of course give users a field that contains their role.

But I don't know how I could then use that information in my MVC application for authentication (using that nice `[Authorize(Roles="admin")]` syntax). All the examples i found for using the identity system use the template site, which I did not use to create this app (I started from an empty project).

Comment: I've never been down the 'roles' road before, but my first instinct would be to look into using ActionFilters and handling the check logic in the `OnActionExecuting` method. Do some research and give it a shot ;)

Answer (score 1):

From my understand i think you can Use the `User.IsInRole()` method or `AuthorizeAttribute` to verify the user in a particular role instead of Membership method or identity method.